# render dynamic html element based on props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component that receives bunch of values as props, amongst them is a prop with a string value that defines the type of 'output html to return'.

something like this, which is of course wrong

```
const WithScrollingText = ({text,boxWidth,tag}) => {
    return boxWidth > 100
    ?   <tag>{text}</tag>
    :   <div className="with-scrolling-text"><div>{text}</div></div>
}
```

and I would call/use this component like this:

```
<WithScrollingText text="Something" boxWidth={250} tag="span"/>
<WithScrollingText text="Something else" boxWidth={250} tag="div"/>
```

and so on

How can I fix the rendering so that when I send 'span' to the component, it renders and returns an span

Answer (score 5):

JSX is just syntactic sugar. Babel transforms `<div>Hello</div>` into `React.createElement("div", {}, "Hello")`.

So in order to have a dynamic tag name, you can use this syntax directly:

```
const WithScrollingText = ({text, boxWidth, tag}) => {
    return boxWidth > 100
    ? React.createElement(tag, {}, text)
    : <div className="with-scrolling-text"><div>{text}</div></div>
}
```

Another approach, should you want to stick with a JSX-style tag, is simply to assign the value of `tag` to a variable with a capital first letter—this tells React to evaluate it as a variable instead of treating it as a string (like it would for React elements, like `div`).

```
const WithScrollingText = ({text, boxWidth, tag}) => {
  const Tag = tag
  return boxWidth > 100
    ? <Tag>{text}</Tag>
    : <div className="with-scrolling-text"><div>{text}</div></div>
}
```